# Adding some boolean conditions in pointcut expression

Tags: aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I'm using some aspect around advice methods. I have methods for controller, service and repository.

```java
@Around("execution(* com.abc..controller..*(..)) && @annotation(audit)")
    public Object controllerAround(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint, Audit audit) throws Throwable {
        //some code here
        return output;
    }

@Around("execution(* com.abc..service.*Impl.*(..))")
    public Object serviceAround(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
        //some code here
        return output;
    }

@Around("execution(* com.abc..persistence.*Impl.*(..))")
    public Object persistenceAround(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
        //some code here
        return output;
    }
```

I have a query that, I need to check in serviceAround method pointcut expression that, whether it's comes from the controllerAround method. I tried using some flags, but spring doesn't support aspectj's if() pointcut primitive.

Any workaround for this will be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 2):

What you actually need is `cflow()` or `cflowbelow()`, not `if()`. But those are also [not supported by Spring AOP](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-pointcuts-designators). So the remaining solution is to use the full power of AspectJ from within Spring via LTW (load-time weaving). How this is done is [nicely documented](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-using-aspectj).

The pointcut would look like this:

```java
execution(* com.abc..service.*Impl.*(..)) &&
cflow(
    execution(* com.abc..controller..*(..)) &&
    @annotation(customAnnotation)
)
```

Or simpler, assuming you do not need the annotation in the advice method:

```java
execution(* com.abc..service.*Impl.*(..)) &&
cflow(execution(* com.abc..controller..*(..)))
```

**Attention:** `cflow()` only works for control flows within one thread, not if e.g. `*Impl*.(..)` is executed in another thread than `controller..*(..)`.

P.S.: Your sample code would probably not work because of a parameter name mismatch between `customAnnotation` and `audit`.

Comment: Tried LTW configurations and when building the project, showing " unsupported pointcut primitive 'cflow' " error.

Comment: Then you did not use AspectJ LTW but Spring AOP.

Comment: Is there any other workarounds with the spring supported primitives !!

Comment: You do not need workarounds, you need a solution: Just use AspectJ instead of Spring AOP. Read the fine manual, please. And next time please also read my answer more carefully.